# Android Instant app navigation create multiple recent task. why?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Hi am working on a android project that am migrating to android instant app. So i have configured instant app modules as per procedures. now my instant app is ready it is working without installation. But 1 problem in that is every call to startActivity create new task, that is when I navigate from different activity every new activity created as a new Task. when I look into recent app section my instant app has many number of running task. I googled regarding this but nothing solved this issue. Any     idea.

Comment: Please post your startActivity and intent creation code.

Comment: And anything that could affect the launch flags, manifest included.